# Git clone automation error Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, sh

I want to automate git clone by using shell script. I use `git clone -b branch "$repository"` but it gives error :

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.

but i have already added the ssh key to my account and i can clone manually using the same command. What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for it. All I miss was to start the ssh-agent and add the id_rsa by

> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
>
> ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Answer (score 0):

> What can i do to fix it?

Double-check what $repository value actually is during the script execution.
That means: echo the line

```
echo git clone -b branch "$repository"
```

Then, if the command displayed by the script is the right one (you can copy-paste it manually, and it is working), make sure the script is used with the same account as yours.